# Inconsistency between help/editing and help/privileges/edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, help-center

[help/privileges/edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) discourages trivial edits:

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

[help/editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) doesn't have this line.

Is the difference on purpose?

If not, can we make the *When should I edit posts?* section in both pages consistent so when I have to remind a user about trivial edits I don't have to remember which link has the correct guidance?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer focuses on the question whether small edits are good or bad, I want to focus more on the reasons, why the pages differ in this aspect.

---

> help/editing doesn't have this line.

Well, that is actually not quite true.

The help/editing post also says that tiny edits are discouraged, it just doesn't highlight it so much:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.

But even with this correction, the pages still differ in the audience:

The privileges page is intended for users who just gained the ability to edit other people posts. It is therefore important to include guidance on when, how and what to edit.

The other page is more for new users who just arrived on the site, asked/answered a question and are now confused, why their post was suddenly edited by some strange other user. This can also be deducted from the page being in the category *Our model*.

Comment: 'But even with this correction, the pages still differ in the audience' - that maybe true but the topic of trivial edits comes up so often that if the line 'Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged' were present on [help/editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) page it's more visible to new users? It almost seems like whoever added the guidance about trivial edits on the edit privileges page forgot to add it on the main help page.

Comment: @sv. Sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean/want? The whole point of my answer is that <1> the information is in the help/editing page (even if not so obvious-highlighted) and <2> that IMHO the help/editing page doesn't need this content. What exactly do you mean with the main-clause of your if-sentence? ("it's more visible to new users?")

Comment: I agree with some parts of your answer but I believe whoever worked on the help pages can clarify if that difference in guidance is in fact intentional. In my question I assumed that it was an error because I see no reason why the two help pages should be any different. I re-read your answer and see that you are arguing against that assumption.

Comment: "The other page is more for new users who just arrived on the site, asked/answered a question and are now confused..." - if this is true, then why does it have the section "When should I edit posts?" Who is "I"? I think the page is also giving guidance to new users so they can edit others' posts if they wanted to.

Comment: @sv. Well it may be that the difference is not intentional (actually quite probably) but my answer attempts to show why this doesn’t need to be changed (IMO).

Comment: Yes, of course but I still think my point is valid, also due to the title of the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

When you find something not correct in grammatical point of view, you can edit it in a proper way, because it will benefit you, I mean, you’ll gain more reputations if you edit someone’s post in a proper way. That’s the main reason for this message:

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged**- try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

I don’t think you need the section “when should I edit posts” because, you can search any post you want and if you see something that needs to be edited then you can do it if you want to. As you know, editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

And you can remind a user which link is a correct guidance or not, that depends on each user to do that. You can see yourself which post need to be edited, no need for a section to tell you when a post need to be edited. And as for links, they are important to be posted on the post, so that the users will know where you got these informations. That’s in my opinion.

I hope this is a good answer. If there’s anything wrong please let me know.